# IIS 7.5 URL rewrite is dropping parts of URLs with a tilde (~)

Tags: iis, rewrite, crucible, fisheye

I'm trying to run a reverse proxy through to a website running locally through IIS to get SSL functioning.  I've got all my rules set up so that I can see 90% of the site perfectly.  The application is Atlassian's Crucible, but I think my issue is more generic than that.

The bad request has the following format (with sanitized names and paths)

https://bar.foo.com/crucible/cru/CR-4/edit-changelog/~author%3Dtheauthor%2520%253Ctheauthor%254040foo.com%253E/repository/

It appears that the URL re-write is dropping everything after the ~ character in the request.

For my inbound rewrite rule I've tried

```
crucible(.*)
^crucible(.*)
^/crucible(.*)
^/crucible(.*)$
```

And about a dozen other variations.  I've also done this with the 'apply query string' box both checked and unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured out a way to get the application to work correctly.  The correct UR is

```
crucible(.*)(~.*)?
```

Then I pass the URL to my site with a suffix of

```
{R:1}{R:2}
```

And it now works.